# Change the Laplace equation to an equation for radial function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spherical-coordinates, laplacian

I have come across some difficulties in this question.

> Given the Laplacian equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$: $\Delta u = 0$,set $$\bar{u}(r) = \int_{|x| = r}u(x)d\sigma$$ with $x = \left(r, \sigma\right)$ is the spherical coordinate of $x$.
> How can I deduce the equation for $\bar{u}$ from the Laplace equation?

I think I can't compute $u$ according to $\bar{u}$. Is there any way to work around this?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: If u was radial, then $\bar{u}=C_n r^{n-1} u$. Moreover, an equation for $\bar{u}$ should only contain radial derivatives up to second order. So computing radial derivatives of $\bar{u}$, initially in the case when $u$ is radial might help. The Laplacian in spherical coordinates may also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're looking for, but if you are allowed to use the mean value property of harmonic functions, that is, $$u(0)= \frac1{n \omega_n r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B_r} u(x) \, d \mathcal H^{n-1}_x$$ where $\omega_n$ is the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$ then $$\bar u (r) = n \omega_n u(0) r^{n-1} $$ for all $r>0$.

---

If you a trying to prove the mean-value formula then you've written the formula for $\bar u$ wrong: it should be $$\bar u (r) =\frac1{n \omega_n r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B_r} u(x) \, d \mathcal H^{n-1}_x.  $$ Then you want to change coordinates to obtain $$\bar u (r) = \frac1{n \omega_n r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B_r} u(x) \, d \mathcal H^{n-1}_x = \frac1{n \omega_n }  \int_{\partial B_1} u(ry) \, d \mathcal H^{n-1}_y $$ then differentiate which gives \begin{align*}
\bar u '(r) &= \frac1{n \omega_n }  \int_{\partial B_1} \nabla u(ry)\cdot y \, d \mathcal H^{n-1}_y\\
&=\frac1{n \omega_n r^{n-1}}  \int_{\partial B_r} \nabla u(x)\cdot \frac x r \, d \mathcal H^{n-1}_x.
\end{align*} Since the outward point unit normal $\nu$ is precisely $x/r$, it follows that \begin{align*}
\bar u '(r) &=\frac1{n \omega_n r^{n-1}}  \int_{\partial B_r} \nabla u(x)\cdot \nu(x) \, d \mathcal H^{n-1}_x \\
&= \frac1{n \omega_n r^{n-1}}  \int_{ B_r} \Delta u(x)\, d x\\
&=0
\end{align*} using Green's formula. Hence, $\bar u$ is constant, so $$\bar u(r) = \lim_{r\to 0^+}\bar u(r) = u(0). $$

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Your answer is even more than I mean to look for.

Comment: You’re welcome:)